# MarionetteJS - Not able to render the data using toJSON function

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I am using `HandlebarsJS` plugin to render my templates. I am getting error while i call the rendering function.

when i console the `this.model.toJSON()`, i am getting correct datas, as well I console the "homeEditTemp" I am getting my templates too..

But when i pass my data to template i am getting error as : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

here is my code :

```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'marionette',
        'hbs!scripts/templates/home/homeEditTemp'],
        function ($,_,Backbone, Marionette, homeEditTemp) {
            "use strict";
            window.socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

            socialApp.homeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

                initialize : function (model) {
                    this.model = model;
                },

                render : function () {
console.log(this.model.toJSON()) // works fine
console.log(homeEditTemp) // works fine.
                    this.$el.html(homeEditTemp(this.model.toJSON())); // throws the error..
                }

            });

            return socialApp.homeView;
    });
```

here is my `handlebars` template :

```
<form>
     <div class="control-group">
         <label for="firstName" class="control-label"> First name:</label>
         <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="{{firstName}}"/>
     </div>
     <div class="control-group">
         <label for="lastName" class="control-label"> Last name:</label>
         <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" value="{{lastName}}"/>
     </div>
     <div class="control-group">
         <label for="email" class="control-label">Phone number:</label>
         <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="{{email}}"/>
     </div>
     <button class="btn js-submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

**update :**

when i manually assign the value, it works fine like this:

```
render : function (model) {
                var obj = {
                    "firstName" : "testFirstName ",
                    "lastName" : " test lastName"
                }
                this.$el.html(homeEditTemp(obj));
            }
```

what would be the issue?

when i console my model it show like this:

```
Object {model: s}model: s_changing: false_events: Object_pending: false_previousAttributes: Objectattributes: Objectchanged: Objectcid: "c6"__proto__: n__proto__: Object
```

Comment: at first you need to compile your template var tpl = function () { return  Handlebars.compile(homeEditTemp)} then you can use this
this.$el.html(tpl(this.model.toJSON()));

Comment: I am using special plug-in for marionette, which is not required such a process. it woks fine with demo.

Comment: Did you check if this.$el is specified?

Comment: Marionette, automatically assigns a "div" if nothing specified.

Comment: Why are you changing the default implementation of render of Marionette.ItemView? You need to do something after render?

Comment: I agree, but it was shown the error, that's the reason i tried this way.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to compile your template

```
var tpl = function () {
     return Handlebars.compile(homeEditTemp);
}
```

Then you can use this

```
this.$el.html(tpl(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Comment: Please have a look on my comments.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
socialApp.homeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
template:homeEditTemp,
initialize : function (model) {
    this.model = model;
},

render : function () {
    var output = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(output);
    return this;
}
```

});

but @vahan is right and you don't need to overwrite the render method usually, just have the template and model variable set and marionette will take care of it

Answer (score -1):

I changed the `model` - implementation like this, it works for me.

```
initialize : function (arg) {
                this.model = arg.model; //it works!
            }
```

instead of :

```
initialize : function (model) {
                this.model = model; //i am not directly got the model here..?
            }
```

Comment: `Marionette.ItemView` extends from `Backbone.View`, which means when you are initializing your `socialApp.homeView` like `var yourViewnew = new socialApp.homeView({model: yourModelInstance})`, it will be implicitly set `this.model` for your ItemView, so you don't need to set it explicitly in `initialize` method of ItemView. [Here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-130) is the list of all attributes which will be setted automatically if you are passing them to Backbone.View when initializing it.